# Finding if input has exactly one pair and zero or more triplets java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am a Java Developer and I was on a interview with an algorithm problem which I cannot seem to solve nor find a solution already for it, but I'm really curious how it can be solved.

Here is the problem.

> You’re working on making some mini-games, and you’ve decided to make a simpler variant of the game Mahjong. In this variant, players have a number of tiles, each marked 0-9. The tiles can be grouped into pairs or triples of the same tile. A “complete hand” is defined as a collection of tiles where all the tiles can be grouped into any number of triples (zero or more) and exactly one pair, and each tile is used in exactly one triple or pair. Write a function that takes a string representing a player’s tiles in no particular order, and returns the string “COMPLETE” if the hand is complete, and “NOT COMPLETE” if it is not. Each tile may only be used in a single group (either a pair or a triple). All tiles must be used to complete a hand. There may be a pair and triples of the same tile. A single pair with no triples (ex: 99) is a valid hand. The input will only consist of characters 0-9.
>
> Examples
>
> These three hands would all return “COMPLETE”:
>
> 33344466 -> 333 444 66
> This hand can be grouped into a triple of 3s and 4s, and a pair of 6s
>
> 55555555 -> 555 555 55
> This hand can be grouped into two triples of 5s and a pair of 5s
>
> 22 -> 22
> This hand is a single pair of 2s (no triples are required)
>
> These three hands would all return “NOT COMPLETE”:
>
> 1357
> This hand has tiles which cannot be formed into pairs or triples.
>
> 335577
> This hand has three pairs, a complete hand must have exactly one pair.
>
> 666888
> This hand has two triples, but no pairs.

Comment: This is a very basic, simple exercise. Stack Overflow isn't the right site for 'hey how do I start'. What did you try? What ideas have you applied?

Comment: If I'm interviewing a potential new hire and they can't do an exercise, that doesn't have to be a problem. But if they just sort of stare at something (the problem, or me, or the wall) for 10 minutes getting more and more flustered as we go, that's an easy 'nope'. Talk through what you're thinking about next time. Or if you did: Talk _us_ through - write down what ideas you have to try to tackle this.

Comment: I think it can be done in one line of code, but the big hint is: It's complete if the quantity of each tile is a multiple of 3, except one quantity may be a multiple of 3 plus 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method implements the important part. It should be easy to understand given the comments.

```
public static boolean isComplete(String s) {
    // map characters to counts; if only digits, could have just stored in array-of-counts
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    s.chars().forEach(c -> map.put(c, map.getOrDefault(c, 0)+1));
    // check that there is exactly 1 pair, and any number of triples, and no left-overs
    boolean foundPair = false;
    for (int v : map.values()) {
        v %= 3; // keep only remainder modulo-three, as triples can be freely ignored
        if (v == 2 && !foundPair) {
            foundPair = true;                
        } else if (v != 0) {
            return false; // only triples (or 1 pair) allowed!
        } 
    }
    return foundPair;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution.
It is not the only solution. Refer to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76241980/finding-if-input-has-exactly-one-pair-and-zero-or-more-triplets-java#comment134450634_76241980) from @Bohemian.
(Explanations after the code.)

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Mahjongs {
    private static final String  COMPLETE = "COMPLETE";
    private static final String  NOT_COMPLETE = "NOT COMPLETE";

    private static String isComplete(String hand) {
        String msg = "Tile %d is not valid: '%c'";
        String result = COMPLETE;
        if (hand == null) {
            result = NOT_COMPLETE;
        }
        else {
            hand = hand.strip();
            if (hand.length() < 2) {
                result = NOT_COMPLETE;
            }
            else {
                char[] tiles = hand.toCharArray();
                Arrays.sort(tiles);
                char last = tiles[0];
                if (!Character.isDigit(last)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(msg, 0, last));
                }
                int count = 1;
                int doubles = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i < tiles.length; i++) {
                    if (!Character.isDigit(tiles[i])) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(msg, i, tiles[i]));
                    }
                    if (tiles[i] == last) {
                        count++;
                        if (count == 3) {
                            count = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (count == 1) {
                            result = NOT_COMPLETE;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (count == 2) {
                            doubles++;
                            if (doubles != 1) {
                                result = NOT_COMPLETE;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        count = 1;
                        last = tiles[i];
                    }
                }
                if (count == 1) {
                    result = NOT_COMPLETE;
                }
                else if (count == 2) {
                    doubles++;
                }
                if (result.equals(COMPLETE)  &&  doubles != 1) {
                    result = NOT_COMPLETE;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isComplete("33344466"));
        System.out.println(isComplete("55555555"));
        System.out.println(isComplete("22"));
        System.out.println(isComplete("1357"));
        System.out.println(isComplete("335577"));
        System.out.println(isComplete("666888"));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

- Method `isComplete` is the method you were asked to write. It takes a single, `String` parameter and returns a `String` which is either *COMPLETE* or *NOT_COMPLETE*.
- Firstly, the method checks the validity of its parameter. While not explicitly mentioned in the problem statement, I think it's always a good idea to do so.

  - If the method parameter is null, the method returns *NOT_COMPLETE*, otherwise...
  - Remove leading and trailing spaces from the parameter.
  - `hand` is complete if it contains at least a single pair, hence the length of the parameter must be at least 2, so if the length is less than 2, the method returns *NOT_COMPLETE*.
- Convert the parameter to an array of `char`.
- Sort the array (since the question does not explicitly state that `hand` is sorted).
- Save the first element of the array in variable `last`.
  (There must be a first element because, at this point, the array contains at least two elements.)
- Iterate through the characters in the array, starting from the second character.
- If a character is not a digit then the method parameter is illegal and the method throws an exception.
- Variable `count` holds the number of consecutive appearances of a given character. If `count` reaches 3, we have a triple and we start counting again.
- When the "current" character is different to `last`, then if `count` equals one, that means there is only a single, consecutive appearance of a digit and that means that the `hand` is incomplete and therefore the method returns *NOT_COMPLETE*.
- Variable `doubles` holds the number of "pairs". There must only be precisely one double so if we count more than one double, the method returns *NOT_COMPLETE*.
- When the "current" character differs from `last` reset `last` and also reset `count`.
- At the end of the `for` loop, check the value of `count` and update `doubles` if required.
- Also at the end of the `for` loop, check the value of `doubles`. If it is not exactly 1 (one), then the method returns *NOT COMPLETE*.
- Finally, return the value of `result` – which is either *COMPLETE* or *NOT COMPLETE*.

Running the above code produces the following output:

```
COMPLETE
COMPLETE
COMPLETE
NOT COMPLETE
NOT COMPLETE
NOT COMPLETE
```